# Video files in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, video-streaming, motion-detection

I want to read video file(.avi or .mov) and detect motion and edges using Opencv.Can u help me with code?I want to create a GUI in which we can select the video file,then we can carry out image processing functions in opencv?

Comment: bro, its not going to be easy. You will still need to learn the basics yourself.

Comment: http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/ Check this book. Simple and concise and will help you getting started with OpenCV

Answer (score 12):

**How to read a video file**:

- [Read video file and display it on a window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639405/176769) (C API)
- [Read video file and display it on a window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408961/176769) (C++ API)
- [Read video file, convert it to grayscale then display it on a window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444370/176769) (C API)

**How to track/detect motion**:

- [Opencv Motion detection with tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7020220/176769)
- [How to do motion tracking of an object using video?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4701997/176769)
- [The OpenCV Video Surveillance / Blob Tracker Facility](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoSurveillance)

**How to detect edges/countours**:

- [Using `cvCanny()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426820/176769)
- [Using `cvCanny()` and `cvFindContours()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289261/176769)
- [Using `cvCornerHarris()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500949/176769)

And for more info on how to detect shapes, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5739247/176769).

Comment: You rock, do you have some kind of database of computer vision FAQ's? :P

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, I'm using `AVI`files.
Call video withe filename, in your main-loop get the next frame and shutdown before  terminating or changing to another video.

```
IplImage  *videoframe;
int videoFps;    
CvCapture *videoCapture=NULL;

int video(char *videoFile) {
    int       key;
    /* load the AVI file */
    videoCapture = cvCaptureFromAVI( videoFile );
    /* always check */
    if( !videoCapture )
        return 0;    
    /* get fps, needed to set the delay */
    videoFps = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( videoCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS );
    /* display video */
    cvNamedWindow( "video", 0 );
}

void videoNext() {
        if ( ! videoCapture ) return;
        videoframe = cvQueryFrame( videoCapture );
        if( !videoframe ) return;
        cvShowImage( "video", videoframe );
        /* quit if user press 'q' */
        int key = cvWaitKey( 1000 / videoFps );
}

void videoShutdown() {
    /* free memory */
    cvReleaseCapture( &videoCapture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "video" );
    return;
}
```

Note: Opencv doesn't support audio playback
On how to use ffmmpeg with opencv see [audio-output-with-video-processing-with-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187745/audio-output-with-video-processing-with-opencv/8191506#8191506)

Answer (score 1):

The shortest example for reading a frame from a video :

```
cap = cv::VideoCapture("foo.avi");
frame = cv::Mat;
cap >> frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the samples included in the python folder for opencv.
They will be found here: opencv\samples\python2

There you will find many of the basic and advanced features of opencv (in the cv2 format) demonstrated. There are also many tutorials (mainly in c++) on the website here: http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Reading and writing video images is here: http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

For initial video capture from AVI:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
img = cv2.VideoCapture.read()
if img:
   print img.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
   print type(img)
# loop through rest of frames reading one at a time
```

Comment: Are you sure about that code? According to the doc, `cv2.VideoCapture.read()` returns a tuple: RetVal, Image.